# Print the first line occurrence of each matching pattern with sed

Tags: regex, linux, awk, sed

I would like to filter the output of the utility last based on a variable set of usernames.

This is sample output from last unfiltered,

```
reboot   system boot  server   Wed Apr  6 13:15 - 14:24  (01:09)    
user1    pts/0        server   Wed Apr  6 13:08 - 13:15  (00:06)    
reboot   system boot  system   Wed Apr  6 13:08 - 13:15  (00:06)    
user1    pts/0        server   Wed Apr  6 13:06 - down   (00:01)    
reboot   system boot  system   Wed Apr  6 13:06 - 13:07  (00:01)    
user1    pts/0        server   Wed Apr  6 12:59 - down   (00:06)
```

What I would like to do is pipe the output of last to sed. Then, using sed I would print the first occurrence of each specified user name i.e. their last log entry in wtmp. The output should appear as so,

```
 reboot   system boot  server   Wed Apr  6 13:15 - 14:24  (01:09)    
 user1    pts/0        server   Wed Apr  6 13:08 - 13:15  (00:06)
```

The sed expression that I particularly like is,

```
last|sed '/user1/{p;q;}'
```

Unfortunately this only gives me the ability to match the first occurrence of one username. Using this syntax is there a way I could specify a multiple of usernames? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` is better fit here than `sed` due to awk's ability to use associative arrays:

```
last | awk '!seen[$1]++'

reboot   system boot  server   Wed Apr  6 13:15 - 14:24  (01:09)
user1    pts/0        server   Wed Apr  6 13:08 - 13:15  (00:06)
```

Comment: This works beautifully, however I'm filtering by usernames within a group and I need some names to be omitted like administrators.

Comment: You can omit anything in awk also like **`awk '!/administrator/ && !seen[$1]++'`**